# The link 'View job listings that include salary' always point to 10000USD

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

While playing numbers on salary [calculator page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/calculator), the button (*View job*) at the bottom redirects to the page which always applies 10000USD, no matter what salary has been calculated. I believe this is not a desired behaviour, since the label on the button suggest to display *that* specific salary.

Tested with Chrome.

Comment: The button `href` is hard-coded with `/jobs?searchTerm=salary%3A10000usd&med=site-ui&ref=salary-calculator`

Answer (score -1):

This is by-design, though perhaps there is a better design.

The goal is simply to link to job listings with salary at all (we include other currencies in the results as well, where they approximate the USD equivalent). We choose 10000 just to exclude spurious data.

Comment: Hmmmmmm. Spurious? I think in Kerblekistan a salary equivalent to USD10k makes you rich. Willing to relocate to Kerblekistan for working is a completely different matter

Comment: Seems fairly unintuitive. Calculate Salary -> View Jobs with [any] salary -> confusion.

Comment: That's an awfully.... questionable design to require a magic number.